# How to ask Mathematica to range all the natural numbers $1<n<500$ which are not multiples of 5?

Tags: number-theory

How can I ask Mathematica to range all the natural numbers $1<n<500$ which are not multiples of 5? I mean I need to get
$$\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,...,499\}$$

Comment: To list two ways to do this: `Array[If[FractionalPart[#/5] == 0, Nothing, #] &, 500]` and `Flatten[Array[{-4, -3, -2, -1} + 5*# &, 100]]` both work.

Comment: @N0va Thank you very much.

Comment: `Drop[Range@500, 5 ;; ;; 5]`

Comment: `Pick[Range[500], Unitize@Mod[Range[500], 5], 1]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. And what about the case if we want to drop two sets, for example multiples of 2 and 5 simultaneously?

Comment: @N0va How about the case if we want to drop two sets, for example, multiples of 2 and 5 simultaneously?

Comment: You can generalize the first option given in my earlier comment to exclude even terms as well by modifying the `If` statement.

Comment: This is clearly a homework question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @yarchik I am not a student. I have Ph. D. and I need to manage some data.  Unfortunately, I am not as familiar with Mathematica as you are.

Comment: Both `Complement[Range[500],Table[n,{n,5,500,5}]]` and `Select[Range[500], Mod[#,5] != 0 &]` might be useful to you for getting a feel for how to do things like this in Mathematica in general!

Comment: In particular, you can either combine criteria inside the function that's given as a second argument of `Select`, e.g. `Mod[#,5] != 0 && Mod[#,2] != 0 &` or feed multiple arguments to `Complement` to achieve what you asked above!

Comment: (Let me know if you have any questions on the syntax here or above, assuming you're relatively new to Mathematica as a language.)

Comment: @thorimur Thank you so much. I always learn a lot on this website from people who spend time and answer.

Comment: Not easy to do with `Span`, but you can extend @Szabolcs's method: `Pick[#, Unitize[Mod[#, 5] Mod[#, 2]], 1] &@Range[500]`

Comment: `Solve[Mod[n, 5] != 0 && 1 < n < 500 && n ∈ PositiveIntegers,
  n]`   ( * not the last method :)  *)

Answer (score 1):

There are very many ways to do this in Mathematica, but
I assume you want something clear and able to be easily
generalized to your needs. I suggest something like:

```
Sort[ n /. FindInstance[ {
  1 < n < 500, n != 5*m}, {n, m}, Integers], 500]]
```

which finds all integers `n` between 1 and 500 exclusive
which are **not** multiples of 5. You can use
other conditions and constraints on `n`.